# Rational number in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ should be integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, rational-numbers, roots-of-unity, integers

Let $\omega = \cos \frac{2\pi}{p} + i \sin \frac{2\pi}{p}$ for some prime number $p > 2$. Then how to prove that if $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, $q$ must be integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ are algebraic integers, meaning that they are solutions of monic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$. But then Gauss's lemma says that all rational solutions of monic polynomials over the integers are in fact integers.

Comment: Why the polynomials have to be monic? I guess they could be monic over $\mathbb{Q}$, but over $\mathbb{Z}$... Also which Gauss' lemma you mean? (for the primitive polynomials or some of the other ones, can you give me some link)

Comment: @brick By definition, algebraic integers are solutions of monic polynomials. Gauss's lemma says that if a monic polynomial factors over Q, it factors over Z.

Comment: Ah, OK, I remembered the lemma. But if this is the definition of algebraic integers, can you explain why all of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ are algebraic integers, please?

Comment: The fact that a ring extension, which is generated by integral elements, is integral, is due to Cayley-Hamilton. You will find this in any textbook about (commutative) algebra.